# Drupal multiple node url aliases

Tags: 7, nodes, redirection, path-aliases

Is it possible to take a field from my node and create a url alias from the content of that field?

Say I have a node type `article`. This gets its normal url via pathauto, but I also wish to be able to create a short url so I can go to `example.com/LS` and I will be redirected to the node.

How can this custom short url be created automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a node they will always use the url `node/[nid]`.

You can use the path auto module to create an url alias for the standard node. Path auto uses the token module to create the url alias for the nodes.

What you can do, is to create a token for the value of the field, and then setup path auto to use the contents of the field when creating the url alias.

Another thing you could do is to use the [ShURLy](http://drupal.org/project/shurly) module, to actual create short urls. You could make a custom module where you created or update the short url for the node when saved, and let ShURLy handle the redirects.

Comment: My node type has already been set up to use the title of the node as the alias like `/articles/node-title-here` and I'd like it to stay this way. But in addition to this it'd be cool if I could also have `/[my_cck_field]` to point to the article. Is this possible with the path auto module?

Comment: Okay so I created a triggered rule that creates an additional alias based on a token when a node is created or updated. It works alright. It works alright except I'd like it to be case sensitive - and well...the alias doesn't redirect (of course) so maybe I should take a look at the ShURLy module.

Comment: I decided it wasn't necessary to create the urls based on my cck field so the [ShURLy](http://drupal.org/project/shurly) module combined with [Shorten URLs](http://drupal.org/project/shorten) did the trick.

Comment: @theory I am having the same issue. And I have installed these two module, and I wanted to auto generate short url. Can you suggest how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_node_insert` and `path_save` like so:

```
function mymodule_node_insert {
  $nid = $node->nid;
  $path = array(
    'source' => 'node/' . $nid,
    'alias'  => 'my/other/path',
  );
  path_save($path);
}
```

This will add an additional alias after the node is created. This won't interrupt Pathauto, so you'll have both aliases active.